# limit of $\sqrt[n]{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question. I was asked to find the limit of

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2}$$
Now, assuming I can use the fact that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$$then I can just say the  original sequence converges to $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n}\cdot\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = 1$$
The multiplication law for limits has already been proven. Is this sufficient, or do I have to prove in a way that the sequence $$x_n = \sqrt[n]{n^2}$$ can be split up into two seperate sequences?

Comment: $$\sqrt[n](n^2)=(\sqrt[n] n)^2$$

Comment: It is sufficient, your argument is correct.

Comment: Okay, good to know, thanks!

Comment: the searched limit is equal to $1$

Comment: The limit of a product is the product of the limits if they exist. Hence the limit of a square is the square of the limit, if it exists.